# Int value Persist

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2, nstimer, ios9.2

I want to implement longpressgesture when my touchbegan method there. I am using NSTimer and record the counter when counter became 3 . I recognized that is long press. But when i release the button and then again press mycounter persist previous value and increment on previous value .Although I am assign counter egual to zero . Please help any help would be apperciated.

```
 var counter : Int = 0
  var timer :NSTimer?

 override public func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        timer = NSTimer()
        counter == 0;
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func updateCounter() {
       print(counter++)
        if (counter > 3){
            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil;
        }
    }
 override public func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        timer!.invalidate()
          timer = nil;
        counter == 0;

    }
  override public func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {



        if (counter>=3){
            print("hello")

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you decide not to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Because long press gesture selector not called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the classic equation `==` versus assign `=` operator confusion

```
timer = NSTimer() // this line is actually not needed
counter = 0

...

timer?.invalidate() // better use question mark to avoid a potential crash
timer = nil
counter = 0
```

and remove all semicolons.